# an Error [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: node.js

working with Node JS and when I start using command `npm start` occured following error in the command line

`[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...` 
how could I fixed this problem?
**edit**
my complete error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\2020 technologies\node\curd_app\server\routes\router.js:11:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\2020 technologies\node\curd_app\server.js:29:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**router.js**

```
route.get('/',services.homeRoutes); //this is line 11



route.get('/add-user',services.add_user)



route.get('/update-user',services.update_user)

module.exports = route
```

**render.js**

```
exports.homeRoutes = (req,res) => {
    res.render('index');
}

exports.add_user = (req,res) =>{
    res.render('add_user');
}

exports.update_user = (req,res) =>{
    res.render('update_user');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your launch file has an error in it which crashes the app. To fix this error, you need to find and fix the bug(s) in your launch file. Under the error message you posted, you can normally find more details where the error happened...

When you've done that, normally nodemon restarts the app automatically. If not, you can simply type `rs` in the console and restart the app.

Comment: unable to find any error here. because last time this app was working fine. then today occurred this problem here

Comment: Can you send me then the complete error please? @Ranawaka

Comment: sure Please see My Updates in question

Comment: There you have the error: `router.js:11:7`. In the router.js file in line 11 @Ranawaka

Comment: Please add the nodejs code to the question so we can figure out what the problem is

Comment: plese see router.js

Comment: Can you please add services.homeRoutes to the question too

Comment: Please see render.js

Comment: I don't see where the `get()` method gets called. I need to see this part of code where the error is produced